# Не могу нормально подключить jquery и fancybox

Tags: jquery, fancybox

На этом сайте тренеруюсь делать ленгдин, пытаюсь подрубить fancybox, но пишет ошибку Uncaught TypeError: $(...).fancybox is not a function, никак не могу это исправить...
Подключаю так:

```
<!-- Connect Fancybox.source -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/landing/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/landing/fancybox/source/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/landing/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
<!-- Connect Fancybox.helpers -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/landing/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/landing/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-media.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/landing/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js"></script>
<!-- Connect Fancybox.lib -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/landing/fancybox/lib/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.6.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/landing/fancybox/lib/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/landing/fancybox/lib/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
```

На этой странице можно увидеть все то о чем я написал.
http://www.mebeldarom24.ru/landing/landing.html

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галочка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Порядок подключения должен быть такой:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/landing/fancybox/lib/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/landing/fancybox/source/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/landing/fancybox/lib/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.6.pack.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/landing/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/landing/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-media.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/landing/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js"></script>
```

Сначала jquery, потом fancybox, потом все плагины для него.
И не подключайте несколько раз jquery

Comment: Смена подключаемых файлов результата не дала, по кнопке "Получить консультацию" так ничего и не отрывается, хотя URL меняется.

Comment: Ошибка пропала?

Comment: @sidirovich поставьте подключение jquery самым первым

Comment: поставил как у тебя, ничего не поменялось...

Comment: @sidirovich у Вас файл /landing/fancybox/source/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.js пустой

Comment: @sidirovich и последнее у Вас 5 блоков с id «popupbutton» и по этим кнопкам открывают всплывающие  окна

Answer (score -1):

для понимания прочитай это http://saitsozdanie.ru/modx/pri-ispolzovanii-shopkeeper-oshibka-oshibka-typeerror-fancybox-is-not-a-function.html - ошибка скорее всего в версии jquery

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать выдержку ответа здесь, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника. Ответы-ссылки могут стать недействительными в случае изменения страницы, на которую дана ссылка.

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.